# Is there a web service for email lists?

Tags: gratis, hosted, mailing-list

I know of [sympa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympa) and [GNU Mailman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Mailman) and currently, my university offers the possibility for email lists.

However, I wonder if there is a free (as in beer) publicly usable service which allows the creation of email lists. Users should be able to register /unregister themselves. Both, sympa and Mailman are ok (there might be more), but I am asking for a hosted service.

Email lists such as mailman are services used to communicate / share information. You can send an email e.g. to `lists@students.kit.edu` and the service sends the email to all subscribed students at KIT. They might also offer an archive, but that is not so important. I am only asking for the very basic service. If there are many free services which offer this functionality, then I might ask for more.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview) and [Yahoo! Groups](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo) has that feature. I haven't used Yahoo Groups in a long time.

You could also research what software this site uses: https://sourceware.org/lists.html

Comment: Also https://groups.io now